# How to convert gff to gtf?

Tags: rna-seq, gtf, gff

My annotation file is in .gff format. I would like to convert it to .gtf format or to know if there is a way to directly download the annotation file in .gtf format?

I am working on sequences from the P Falicparum 3D7.

Comment: I think the question was already extensively answered here:
https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/how-to-convert-gff3-to-gtf2

Comment: Thank you for your awnser

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to use `agat_convert_sp_gff2gtf.pl` from [AGAT](https://github.com/NBISweden/AGAT) because you loose information with `gffread`.
e.g here a gff example:

```
##gff-version 3
scaffold625 maker   gene    337818  343277  .   +   .   ID=CLUHARG00000005458;Name=TUBB3_2
scaffold625 maker   transcript  337818  343277  .   +   .   ID=CLUHART00000008717;Parent=CLUHARG00000005458
scaffold625 maker   CDS 337915  337971  .   +   0   ID=CLUHART00000008717:cds;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 340733  340841  .   +   0   ID=CLUHART00000008717:cds;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 341518  341628  .   +   2   ID=CLUHART00000008717:cds;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 341964  343033  .   +   2   ID=CLUHART00000008717:cds;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    337818  337971  .   +   0   ID=CLUHART00000008717:exon1;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    340733  340841  .   +   0   ID=CLUHART00000008717:exon2;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    341518  341628  .   +   2   ID=CLUHART00000008717:exon3;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    341964  343277  .   +   2   ID=CLUHART00000008717:exon4;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   five_prime_UTR  337818  337914  .   +   .   ID=CLUHART00000008717:five_prime_utr;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   three_prime_UTR 343034  343277  .   +   .   ID=CLUHART00000008717:three_prime_utr;Parent=CLUHART00000008717
```

with gffread you get:

```
scaffold625 maker   transcript  337818  343277  .   +   .   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   exon    337818  337971  .   +   .   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   exon    340733  340841  .   +   .   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   exon    341518  341628  .   +   .   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   exon    341964  343277  .   +   .   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   CDS 337915  337971  .   +   0   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   CDS 340733  340841  .   +   0   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   CDS 341518  341628  .   +   2   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
scaffold625 maker   CDS 341964  343033  .   +   2   transcript_id "CLUHART00000008717"; gene_id "CLUHARG00000005458";
```

while with AGAT you get

```
scaffold625 maker   gene    337818  343277  .   +   .   ID CLUHARG00000005458 ; Name TUBB3_2 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458
scaffold625 maker   mRNA    337818  343277  .   +   .   ID CLUHART00000008717 ; Parent CLUHARG00000005458 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    337818  337971  .   +   0   ID "CLUHART00000008717:exon1"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    340733  340841  .   +   0   ID "CLUHART00000008717:exon2"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    341518  341628  .   +   2   ID "CLUHART00000008717:exon3"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   exon    341964  343277  .   +   2   ID "CLUHART00000008717:exon4"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 337915  337971  .   +   0   ID "CLUHART00000008717:cds"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 340733  340841  .   +   0   ID "CLUHART00000008717:cds"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 341518  341628  .   +   2   ID "CLUHART00000008717:cds"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   CDS 341964  343033  .   +   2   ID "CLUHART00000008717:cds"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   five_prime_UTR  337818  337914  .   +   .   ID "CLUHART00000008717:five_prime_utr"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
scaffold625 maker   three_prime_UTR 343034  343277  .   +   .   ID "CLUHART00000008717:three_prime_utr"  ; Parent CLUHART00000008717 ; gene_id CLUHARG00000005458 ; transcript_id CLUHART00000008717
```

So you can see as example that `Name=TUBB3_2` from the gene feature disappeared with `gffread`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `gffread` to convert `gff` to `gtf2`, below is from [the manual](http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/stringtie/gff.shtml):

> In order to see the GTF2 version of the same transcripts, the -T
>   option should be added:
>
> ```
> gffread -E annotation.gff -T -o- | more
> ```
>
> The examples above also show that gffread can be used to convert a
>   file between GTF2 and GFF3 file formats.

Comment: Thk for your awnser

Answer (score 1):

Actually I started a mini-review about the tools to do such conversion.
You can find it here: 
https://github.com/NBISweden/GAAS/blob/master/annotation/knowledge/gff_to_gtf.md

As I mentioned earlier they do not behave all the same way...

Answer (score 0):

You can try bioinfokit (https://github.com/reneshbedre/bioinfokit) in python.

````
from bioinfokit.analys import gff

gff.gff_to_gtf(file="yourfile.gff3") 
# The converted gtf file will be saved in the same working directory.
```
````